# C get size of hex shellcode

Tags: c, char

How can I get the size of my char pointer

```
char *data = "\x30\x2e\x30\x2e\x30\x2e\x30\x3a\x30";
```

Using `strlen(data)` or `sizeof(data)` always returns `1`

Comment: Given that declaration, `sizeof(data)` should yield 4 or 8 (the size of a pointer), and `strlen(data)` should return 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strlen` counts characters in C string till it encounters 0. It maybe
tricky to get length of shell code using `strlen` since shell code
may contain 0 bytes in between; it appears there even exists notion of null free shell code ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode#Null-free_shellcode)) -  in that case I believe you can use `strlen`. Otherwise you can try:

```
char data[] = "\x30\x2e\x30\x2e\x30\x2e\x30\x3a\x30"; // you were missing \ in the beginning
printf("%zu", sizeof(data));
```

gives you 10 bytes.

Comment: Thanks! I had to use sizeof(data) - 1 to get the correct size of the code. And yes it my actual shell code I had \x00 in 2nd place that's why it was not working :) Thank you for the explanations

Answer (score 1):

`strlen( data )` gives **11**. It is the number of characters in the string literal `"x30\x2e\x30\x2e\x30\x2e\x30\x3a\x30"` that preceed the terminating zero. 
`sizeof( data )` returns the size of the pointer itself and is implementation defined. Usually it is either 4 or 8 bytes and this value does not depend of the size of the string literal the pointer points to..

You can ask why strlen( data ) returns 11. It is because you forgot the first backslash before  the first character `"x30..."`. Thus the string literal starts from three characters 'x', '3', and '0'. All other characters are specified like hexadecimal escape characters  .

I think you mean

```
"\x30\x2e\x30\x2e\x30\x2e\x30\x3a\x30"
```

If the system where the program runs is used ASCII coding then this string literal is equivalent to

```
0.0.0.0:0
```

Answer (score 1):

Defines like this:

```
char data[] = "x30\x2e\x30\x2e\x30\x2e\x30\x3a\x30";
```

Then use `sizeof(data)`